# How to insert rows in one table based on another copying previous values in destination table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (C1 INT);
CREATE TABLE T2 (C1 INT, C2 INT);

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (9), (10), (12), (13), (21), (53), (111);
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (10, 3), (12, 6), (21, 9);

Desired values in T2
C1  C2
10  3
12  6
13  6 -- duplicate value from row C1=12
21  9
53  9 -- duplicate value from row C1=21
111 9 -- duplicate value from row C1=21
```

How does one insert rows into table T2,
that are in T1, matching on column C1
where the values of the columns come from previous rows in T2 ordered by C1?

If there are no previous values, i.e. C1=9, no new row should be inserted.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Tables in SQL are inherently unordered.  How do you define the "previous row" in T2?

Comment: This is for SQL Server 2012.

Comment: "previous rows in T2 ordered by C1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into T2 (C1, C2)
  select a.C1, b.C2
  from T1 a
  cross apply (
    select top 1
      C2
    from T2
    where T2.C1 < a.C1
    order by T2.C1 desc
  ) b
  where a.C1 not in (select C1 from T2)
```

you can also use a correlated subquery instead of cross apply, but it takes an extra check to avoid inserting null if there is no previous C1.

Comment: This gets the exact output you listed, is it what you are after?

Comment: yes, its exactly what I'm looking for and I've tested it too. I'm just waiting a bit before marking it as the answer in case someone else comes up with a better solution / finds a problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the T2.C2 in ascending order, you can use MAX aggregate function with an ORDER BY clause

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT T1.C1 AS t1C1, T2.C1 AS t2C1,
         MAX(T2.C2) OVER(ORDER BY T1.C1) AS C2
  FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1
  )
  SELECT t1C1 AS C1, C2
  FROM cte
  WHERE C2 IS NOT NULL AND t2C1 IS NULL
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9632/2)

Answer (score -2):

```
create table t2 
as 
select * from t1
```

and there is another opportunity

```
UNION and UNION ALL
```

...

and

```
select distinct * from t2
```